# Comma before adverbials

Tags: commas, adverbials

A friend asked me about a comma in the following sentence:

*The project took place in several centers between January and February.*

Should there be one between *centers* and *between*? I really am not sure...

It seems to me that in formal writing the comma is necessary as it's the project taking place in several centers that happened between January and February not the centers themselves.

However, the meaning is clear without the comma. It's not like he's saying "I had many girls between 10 and 15 OR I had many girls, between 10 and 15".

Comment: Are we to infer that your friend's project was based on the — ahem — *'involvement'* of 10-to-15-year-old girls?

Comment: You most certainly are not :) That was just an examplary sentence in which IMHO the comma makes all the difference.

Comment: If the sentence is ambiguous, as in the second example, a comma may resolve it. But if it's not ambiguous, you can write it either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comma is not needed, but the sentence should say "during January and February. There are no days "between" January and February.